# The application runs so well, but Jasper Report doesn't give the display

Tags: java, netbeans, report

I have problem with the display of my report (using Jasper Report). I've made the first report and it ran so well. But this second report didn't give anything to see although the application run smoothly. It took some time and give no result at all.
When i stopped that application, there is a message shown in Netbeans editor like this `"Java Result: -805306369"` . How can i do solve this? Thanks for any reply

Comment: Show your code, and show any stack traces.

Comment: Have you checked your data source?